# fetching data from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables tblteacher and tblattendance having tshortname field in common.Now i want to show tshortname from tblteacher and status as 'yes' if for particular date in tblattendance i also have tshortname in tblattendance otherwise status should be 'no'

```
select distinct(tblteacher.teachername),tblteacher.tshortname,
if(strcmp(tblteacher.tshortname,tblattendance.tshortname) and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01','no','yes') as status 
from tblteacher,tblclass,tblattendance
```

here is the data which is being shown when i execute the above query

[image]

The data shown for date-'2013-07-01' is correct for some teachers.I am not getting where the problem is.Please help me to solve this problem

Update:

```
select distinct(tblteacher.tshortname),if (tblteacher.tshortname not in(SELECT  
distinct(t.tshortname) from tblteacher t left join tblattendance a on t.tshortname=a.tshortname 
where a.attdate='2013-07-03'),'no','yes') as status from tblteacher;
```

[image]

Now i am always getting 42 rows and correct status according to the date in attenadance table

Comment: You are selecting from 3 tables without joining on any fields.  That's bad.

Comment: i have tried by joining also but consider the case when you have entry in tblteacher but not in tblattendance for particular date then it will not show that row but we need that row with status no....you are free to use join i will implement that but solve my problem

Comment: Then use a left join with whatever mssql function is equivalent to ifnull().

Comment: i tried to use but couldn't form an appropriate query.Please you help me and give me the whole query

Comment: No, for two reasons.  First, I don't support elective helplessness, and second, I don't use mysql so I would probably do it incorrectly.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is an  option, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a classic cartesian join between the tables.

you need to tell the database how to match the data in the various tables like this:

```
select distinct 
    (tblteacher.teachername),tblteacher.tshortname,
    if(strcmp(tblteacher.tshortname,tblattendance.tshortname) and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01','no','yes') as status 
from 
    tblteacher
        join tblclass
            on tblteacher.tshortname=tblattendance.tshortname
        join tblattendance
            on tblteacher.tshortname=tblattendance.teacherShortName
```

In your case, the strcpm will take care of the join in the first two, but will match it to ALL the rows in the third table - which is where you are going wrong.

Edit: From your comment, this might work better for you to get all the rows as expected.

```
select distinct 
    (tblteacher.teachername),tblteacher.tshortname,
    if(strcmp(tblteacher.tshortname,tblattendance.tshortname) and tblattendance.attdate='2013-07-01','no','yes') as status 
from 
    tblteacher
        left outer join tblclass
            on tblteacher.tshortname=tblattendance.tshortname
        left outer join tblattendance
            on tblteacher.tshortname=tblattendance.teacherShortName
```

Comment: your query is returning yes for all values whether i change date

Comment: @rupinder18 Then there is still a cartesian join in the query. I guessed at the relationship between the two tables, but when you have more than one matching row of data in a query and you don't specify what to join tables on, it will return ALL matching rows based on the conditions in your query.

Comment: i have total 42 rows in my tblteacher table and i want that my query always return 42 rows and status as yes and no accordingly

Comment: @rupinder18 I have made an edit to my answer which I hope will assist in your query.

Comment: you have a small error you are joining tblclass and tblteacher but on clause is wrong check the following-where you are joining tblclass in on write tblteacher.tshortname=tblclass.tshortname

Comment: and by this query i am getting 42 rows but for each row status is yes

Answer (score 0):

You need to left join the attendance table and then

```
select if(tblattendance.tshortname is not null and attdate = '2013-07-01', 'yes', 'no') as status
```

Edit: Full Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.tshortname,
    teachername, 
    IF(attdate = '2013-07-01','yes','no') AS status 
FROM tblteacher AS t
LEFT JOIN tblattendance AS a
       ON t.tshortname = a.tshortname
```

Comment: I edited my answer to include the full query. This should work. What incorrect? In your updated question you are using a subquery, which is not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess...

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t.tshortname
      , CASE WHEN a.shortname IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END status
   FROM tblteacher t 
   LEFT
   JOIN tblattendance a 
     ON t.tshortname = a.tshortname 
    AND a.attdate = '2013-07-03';
```